# Mass obligation & travel to different diocese?

Tags: catholicism, mass, ascension

If I attend Mass on Ascension Thursday in my diocese that observes Thursday & travel to a diocese that transfers to that Sunday, do have Sunday obligation since the liturgy will be the same?

Comment: The obligation pertains to the *day*, not to the specific Mass that is said.

Comment: Inverse Question: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/83177/ascension-mass-when-traveling-between-dioceses

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Every Sunday is obligatory unless a particular dispensation applies. The particular Mass text doesn't matter. You can meet your obligation by attending a Nuptial Mass, a Funeral Mass or a Votive Mass as long as it is celebrated that day (or the evening before).

> [Can. 1246 §1.](https://www.vatican.va/archive/cod-iuris-canonici/eng/documents/cic_lib4-cann1244-1253_en.html) Sunday, on which by apostolic tradition the paschal mystery is celebrated, must be observed in the universal Church as the primordial holy day of obligation. The following days must also be observed: the Nativity of our Lord Jesus Christ, the Epiphany, the Ascension, the Body and Blood of Christ, Holy Mary the Mother of God, her Immaculate Conception, her Assumption, Saint Joseph, Saint Peter and Saint Paul the Apostles, and All Saints.

> Can. 1247 On Sundays and other holy days of obligation, the faithful are obliged to participate in the Mass.

Comment: Please add some official, magisterial references supporting this.

Comment: Added some, but this is sorta like trying to prove a negative. The OP is asking whether Sunday obligation still holds because a feast was celebrated on a different day when it has been transferred to Sunday elsewhere. The closest we can get is to show the requirement of Sunday always exists

Comment: You mean if, for example, Easter Sunday were transferred to another day of the week? That's not possible. Sundays are always holy days of obligation.

Comment: @Geremia right, but OP is asking whether Sunday obligation still exists if a feast day is transferred in one place AND someone attends where it was on the original date.